# Removing the watermark from windows 10 desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop, watermark

There is a watermark at the corner of windows 10 desktop showing Os and version information. How do I remove that?

Comment: Are you a member of the Windows Insider Program?

Comment: "How to Remove the Windows 10 Watermark From Insider Program Desktops" https://www.techjunkie.com/remove-windows-10-watermark-desktop/

Comment: @vssher that uses external tools. I have found a way to do it using registry.